# Visual Studio Debugger does not break on NullReferenceException, although checkbox is set in debugging options

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I manually migrated a Visual Studio 2012 "website" to a "ASP web project" to be able to use environment-specific web.configs (using transformation).

After migration my debugger does not stop anymore at exceptions.

In my output view I can see that a NullReferenceException is raised, my HTTP-REST-client receives "400 bad request", but the debugger ignores that exception.

I followed the instructions to enable exceptions ( [How do I allow breaking on 'System.NullReferenceException' in VS2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475464/how-do-i-allow-breaking-on-system-nullreferenceexception-in-vs2010) ). In the dialog "debugging"=>"Exceptions..." NullReferenceExceptions are enabled and resetting all checkboxes does also not help.

Breakpoints are working as expected.

The compiler also has some strange behaviour: compilation will succeed even if the code contains syntax problems. (But this might be a separate issue)

How can I reenable the debugger?

Comment: I the Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions Make sure that the checkbox System.NullReferenceException is checked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue seems to be fixed after I **enabled** "Just My Code" in "Options"=>"Debugging"=>"General". (see also [Visual Studio 2013 "break on handled exceptions" not working, not breaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377297/visual-studio-2013-break-on-handled-exceptions-not-working-not-breaking) ).

Answer (score 3):

Is "Just my code" enabled? You should try to set it as enable and see if it works.

Comment: ops, I see you beat me! :P

Comment: :P But by the way: do you know WHY I have to "enable" this setting? It seems counter intuitive. The "Just" seemed to reduce the breakpoints - but extended the breakpoints instead.

Comment: can this help you?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: @slartidan, look at Andrew Hall's answer on the link you yourself have given in your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21470432/17447 :)  Downvoter: why?